# How to resolve 'unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary' once upgrading to chromedriver 2.25

Tags: windows, protractor

The upgrade of chromedriver to 2.25, or Chrome to version 54 has caused the following error: 
'unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary'.  The location of Chrome has not changed, but it seems that the chromedriver is not looking in a different location?  I'm running this using  a VM (locally is fine with any versioning)

I've tried adding the following to my protractor-config, but this does not have any affect on the error.

```
  capabilities: {
  browserName: 'chrome',
   chromeOptions:'binary': 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/Chrome.exe'}, 
},
```

Is there anything else I can try?  How do I find the path that the chromedriver is currently looking for the binary?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You must upgrade to chromedriver. That is the issue.

[Chrome Driver for Windows](http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.9/chromedriver_win32.zip)

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: I will try that! Thanks! :)